# Arithmetic expressions in for-loop

Tags: bash, shell-script, arithmetic, control-flow

In

```
for (( expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3 )) ; do commands ; done
```

`expr1`, `expr2`, and `expr3` are arithmetic expressions.

- Is `expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3` not an arithmetic expression? `(( expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3 ))` isn't a stand-alone command, so I guess `expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3` isn't an arithmetic expression. Note that `expr1, expr2, expr3` is an arithmetic expression.
- Are `((` and `))`  in the for-loop different from `((` and `))` in command `(( 3 ))`?
- Does `(( expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3 ))` make sense only in for-loop? Or also else where?

Comment: I appreciate any upvote to counteract the unreasonable downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`expr1; expr2; expr3` is not an arithmetic expression since `;` is not a possible operator in arithmetic expressions, as you can see by reading the [syntax of arithmetic expressions in the bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic).

The [syntax of for loops](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-for) gives the form `for ((expr1; expr2; expr3)) ; do commands ; done`, with the semicolons. So the `((…))` bit is not the same thing as an [arithmetic instruction](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs), which doesn't start with `for`.

`((expr1; expr2; expr3))` is part of the [syntax of for loops](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-for). It's only a valid syntactic unit after `for`.

Comment: @BinaryZebra Arithmetic expression is `$(())`, not `((…))`. `((…))` doesn't appear to have a standard name.

Comment: It is difficult to me to single out to which of all three uses of `((` you are referring to in your sentence. I believe that the most common name for a simple `(( ))` is "compound command", as the manual states: `LESS=+'/Compound Commands' man bash`. But "arithmetic instruction" seems to be a new name that doesn't seem to focus on any of them.

Comment: @BinaryZebra “Compound command” and “conditional construct” is a general term that encompass many things beyond `((…))`. “Conditional construct” is not a standard term and does not make much sense for `((…))` since it has a usual meaning in programming languages which in the shell would cover `if` and `case`, and furthermore “conditional expression” is a standard term for a different thing (what's inside `[ … ]` or `[[ … ]]`).

Comment: I did not use “conditional construct” in my comment. And, there is only one possible “Compound command” that looks like `(( ))`, less confusion possible. But if you want to keep your answer as it is, It is all fine with me, no need for anything else.

Comment: @BinaryZebra `for ((…; …; …)); do …; done` is also a compound command.

Comment: Errrr, yes, you are right, it is. But it has a name, a specific name, it is called a `for loop`. And it is not a simple `(( ))`, it is a complex `((...;...;...))` with an added `for` in the front also.